# Creating pflog interface

Tags: networking, freebsd, pf

I'm attempting to create a pflog interface using ifconfig so I can log to more than one file and when I attempt to execute the following command I get this error. I'm attempting this on a vanilla install of the latest FreeBSD.

```
freebsd# ifconfig create pflog1
ifconfig: interface create does not exist
```

Any ideas on how to create a second pflog interface? I cannot seem to find any documentation on this and all the books I can find refer to the above command as if it should work with no trouble... =(

Also some more errors:

```
freebsd# ifconfig -C
lo gif ppp tun faith
freebsd# ifconfig create ppp1
ifconfig: interface create does not exist
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can listen multiple times on the same pflog0 and use bpf filters to
split them up

```
pflogd0 -f /var/log/pf.blocked action block
pflogd0 -f /var/log/pf.passed action pass
pflogd0 -f /var/log/pf.rule.15 rulenum 15
pflogd0 -f /var/log/pf.fxp0 on fxp0
```

(c) [Mike Frantzen](http://www.mail-archive.com/pf@benzedrine.cx/msg01045.html)

PS. right syntax is `ifconfig pflog1 create`